# https://angular.io на сайте как работают ссылки

Tags: angular4, angular-routing, angular

Чтобы перенаправлять пользователя на другую страниц я использую **Routing & Navigation**. На `Inspect Element` показывает код

```
<a _ngcontent-c0="" routerlink="/heroes" routerlinkactive="active">Heroes</a>
```

Но когда смотрю `Inspect Element` сайта **`https://angular.io`** так вижу

```
<a class="nav-link" href="docs" title="Docs">Docs</a>
```

Как это работает без обновлении страницы, там же **`href="docs"`**?

Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Где-то висит слушатель на `a`, который отменяет переход и инициирует внутреннюю смену страницы.

Comment: Я ангуляр не знаю, но с точки зрения js ничего не мешает повесить любое событие на любой элемент и не зависеть от атрибутов вообще

Comment: А вообще ничто не мешает вам почитать исходники сайта angular.io самостоятельно: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio

Comment: Спасибо. Логика стало немного понятный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Angular 4 ссылки работают только внутри приложения.

`Location.go (), Router.navigate () и Router.navigateByUrl ()` отлично подходят для отправки пользователя в другой раздел (маршрут) в приложении Angular 4.

Если вам надо перенаправить в другое приложение, то используете `window.location.href = '...';`. Это изменит страницу на то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Спасибо за исправлению и ответа.